# Rsync always overwrites files on external USB drive with BTRFS

Tags: rsync

On Ubuntu 20 Hyper-V VM rsync always overwrites same files on external USB drive (pass-through drive). Both source and destination are BTRFS.
I checked sizes on both sides - they match. Timestamp looks fine too. Is this a bug in rsync?

`rsync -rvh --delete --progress /mydata/data /mydata_backup/backup/`

tried
`rsync -avh --delete --progress /mydata/data /mydata_backup/backup/` - still same problem. only works with --size-only

Comment: Consider adding `-i` to your rsync command, and then adding the output to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this was a bad USB-SATA firmware/controller, I switched to a different HDD enclosure and the problem is gone.

Comment: Can you share which brand or vendor is the broken one? (`lsusb` should give you the vendor id, which is in the form `ID nnnn:nnnn`)

Answer (score -1):

You're missing the `-t` (`--times`) flag from your command:

```
sudo rsync -rtvh --delete --progress /mypool/data/ /mypool_backup/backup
```

Always use `-t` (or `-a` / `--archive`, which implies it) unless you have a really really good reason for not doing so.

Comment: Added -a, still same issue. Only works with --size-only

Comment: @paul just noticed you're also missing a trailing `/` on the source directory

Comment: @paul is the destination definitely BTRFS and not (say) ExFAT or FAT32?

Comment: Definitely BTRFS